# Is it okay to provide a list of manuscripts that are in preparation?

Tags: phd, cv, biology

I am preparing my CV for a Ph.D. application. Can I include a list of papers that are currently in preparation?

Comment: Yes, but make sure to keep things in balance. 1 published paper and 10 in preparation would be bad.

Comment: it's fine, just put in braces *(in progress)*

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is fine. Having a section on "Work in Progress" is usually (always?) a good option as it shows you are active.

Work in progress can include things nearing completion (in prep) but also things at an earlier stage.